# Distinct 2 Different Columns, How to print total combination in every row

Tags: mysql

Having this query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, DATE FROM MAIN_TAB ORDER BY ID ASC
```

How can I print the total of different combinations for `ID` field, on the front of every row, example `TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUES`:

```
ID    DATE       TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUES
37870 02/07/2018                     3
37870 03/07/2018                     3
37870 04/07/2018                     3
55887 04/07/2018                     2
55887 03/07/2018                     2
61891 02/07/2018                     1
44891 02/07/2018                     1
75891 02/07/2018                     1
```

Comment: is this sample data or output table?

Comment: i can print the ID, DATE column easily with my basic distinct query, what i need after this query is the number of rows for ID in the extra column represented on example picture "TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUES" .

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use count and  group by

```
SELECT ID, DATE, count(*) TOTAL_DISINCT_VALUE
FROM MAIN_TAB 
GROUP BY ID, DATE
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

but looking to you data sample seems you need  cont only for id  so you could use a join  on the count group by id

```
select t.id, a.date, t.TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUE
from  MAIN_TAB a
inner JOIN (
    select id, count(*) TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUE 
    FROM MAIN_TAB 
    group by ID 
) t on a.id = t.id
```

or as suggested by barmar  . count(distinct date)

```
select t.id, a.date, t.TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUE
from  MAIN_TAB a
inner JOIN (
    select id, count(distinct date) TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUE 
    FROM MAIN_TAB 
    group by ID 
) t on a.id = t.id
```

Comment: Finally, it worked with the @Barmar solution with the replace COUNT (*) to COUNT (DISTINCT date). Very TY for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use `group by` clause

```
  SELECT ID, DATE,count(*) as distinct_value FROM MAIN_TAB 
    group by ID, DATE
    ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: i tried this before, but is not that i need . sorry , and TY

Comment: @Isidoro colaco can you share your sample data please as we got from your description image is output sample

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e7gxBPx5pyAPELqh516Hpn/0  please go to this link and show your table structure and data

Comment: Easy sample:

[MAIN_TAB values(37870,'2018-07-02'),(37870,'2018-07-02'),(37870,'2018-07-03'),(37870,'2018-07-04');]

something that results this => (ID,DATE,TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUES) (37870 | 2018-07-02 | 3) + (37870 | 2018-07-03 | 3) + (37870 | 2018-07-04 | 3)

Comment: [MAIN_TAB values(37870,'2018-07-02'),(37870,'2018-07-02'),(37870,'2018-07-03'),(37870,'2018-07-04');]

something that results this => (37870 | 2018-07-02 | 3) + (37870 | 2018-07-03 | 3) + (37870 | 2018-07-04 | 3)

The TOTAL_DISTINCT_VALUES = 3, is the number of the rows for the diferent dates winth a combination with a single ID .

Comment: so here in sample data i found that on date July 02 this id 37870 available 4th times but you want to see count as a 3 on that date right?

Comment: Zaynul, Ty anyway ... May my explanation was not very clear . it works with a @barmar solution .

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select ID,DATE,count(*) as TOTAL_DISINCT_VALUE from MAIN_TAB group by ID,DATE order by ID asc;
```

and replace * with any other column name except ID and DATE.

Comment: He just wants the count by ID, not by ID and date.